# How to preserve query params when use chrome.declarativeNetRequest in Chrome extension manifestv3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

The declarativeNetRequest rule I set

```json
[
  {
    "action": {
      "redirect": {
        "url": "https://another.com/api_2/luckyDog"
      },
      "type": "redirect"
    },
    "condition": {
      "requestMethods": ["get"],
      "urlFilter": "/luckyDog"
    },
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

1. When `http://current.com/api/luckyDog` is requested, it was redirected to `https://another.com/api_2/luckyDog`. This is right.
2. However when I request `http://current.com/api/luckyDog?count=3`, it was redirected to `https://another.com/api_2/luckyDog` too. I expect it to be redirected to `https://another.com/api_2/luckyDog?count=3`.

I don't know how to do that. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `url`, which replaces the entire URL, specify the parts to replace explicitly:

```json
      "redirect": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "another.com",
        "path": "/api_2/luckyDog"
      },
```

Alternatively, use regexFilter + regexSubstitution, which is more flexible, but slower - see [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#example).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the example I want